# TFS 2010: change work item types and retain existing source history

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-workitem, cmmi

We started programming in a project that uses Agile Work Item Templates. Now, there is some history of the code that we want to keep.

Also, we want to change to a customized CMMI template, so it is close to CMMI, but customized, with slightly different work items, also some new/removed ones (for testing purposes, we set it up in a different project).

How can we now merge the source (and history) from the one project with the work items from another project?

From my understanding, you could simply export/import the work item types, but then, all the reports and queries as well as the dashboard would not get updated properly as well? So all scenarios we can come up with now result in a loss of version history (simply importing the current state of the source into newly created project using CMMI and then updating the work items).

Is there a better solution?

(using TFS 2010 and VS 2010)

edit: some useful information to be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2011/05/17/tfs-integration-tools-where-does-one-start-part-3-dust-has-settled-did-it-work.aspx - like me, you will probably especially run into trouble with the ProcessBuildTemplates

Comment: Have you considered using the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe)? I'm not sure about the successful migration of work items for Team Projects using different templates, but I've been able to successfully migrate code with its history between Team Projects.

Comment: Even with the same version of TFS? Can you migrate between TFS 2010 and TFS 2010 retaining the history, delete and re-create the old project and migrate the code including history back?

Comment: All the migrations I've done have been from a TFS 2010 to the same TFS 2010. I think it's possible to do what you are describing but I would test the process on a separate testing Team Collection or a playground TFS, both to make sure it works and that it will provide the result you need. This kind of tasks with TFS are no walk in the park.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing me there. Attempting the migration right now.. well.. documentation could be better, though once it is installed, the GUI is nearly self-explanatory and conflicts are managable so far though the process is slow. Plus, I need an intermediate SQL Server from what it looks like. Also, I hope that "migration" does not mean delete the items from the source....

Comment: I agree that the extra SQL Server database is awkward to say the least. The migration does not mean the deletion from the source, so you can use it with peace of mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe)? I'm not sure about the successful migration of work items for Team Projects using different templates, but I've been able to successfully migrate code with its history between Team Projects.

Comment: well, well, well earned answer. :) many thanks! (btw, for anyone else attempting this: 3h+ for ~35k version/add items, after what seemed like light use (~3 months with just a couple of developers)).

Comment: One more question: is there a "clean" way to do this? I created a fresh project to migrate all the source from another project, but stumbled across the BuildProcessTemplates already being present, and.. not knowing what I did.. I think I specified a non-existing target changeset and I think my migration does not recover now. Start from scratch or is there a way to fix this?